# How can I check if the value of each array is zero with respect to the key?

Tags: php

I want to check if the value of each array is zero relative to the key and if the value in the array with the key [5417736] was zero for example:

```
array (1) {[5417736] => string (2) "10"}
array (1) {[5417736] => string (2) "10"}
array (1) {[5417736] => string (1) "0"}
```

in the array and go to the next key, for example:

```
array (1) {[1899299] => string (2) "10"}
array (1) {[1899299] => string (2) "10"}
```

in top array [$key] is order_code from order model and $value is product_qty from product model

my code :

```
if ($_POST["order_code"])
        {
            foreach ($_POST["order_code"] as $key => $value)
            {
                $orders = Order::where("order_code", $_POST["order_code"][$key])->get();
                foreach ($orders as $order)
                {
                    $products = Product::find($order->product_id);
                    $array_item = array(
                        $order->order_code => $products->product_count
                    );
                    foreach ($array_item as $k => $val)
                    {
                        var_dump($array_item);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

this is table customer :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1qb3.jpg)

updated description :

I have two orders here that are specified with the order code `[5417736]`, `[1899299]` Order with code `5417736` has three products and one of the products has zero value `array (1) {[5417736] => string (1) "0"}` Now I want to check each order in which order the number of products is still zero, and if an order had a product with a value of `zero`, Ignore it and check the next order if it did not have a product with zero, the value in the order_lack column for each I can change the order

Comment: I don't understand your description of what you actually want to achieve here. And `if (isset($_POST["order_code"]) == $_POST["order_code"])` does not make much sense to begin with - `isset` returns a boolean.

Comment: What does "zero relative to the key" mean?

Comment: `5417736` and `1899299 ` are orders? If so I think you could just do `if(in_array(0, $orders)) { //there is a 0}` in place of `foreach ($orders as $order)` alternatively it'd be in place of `$array_item` loop.

Comment: @hobbs I think I could not express my meaning correctly
I have two orders here that are specified with the order code
[5417736], [1899299] Order with code 5417736 has three products and one of the products has zero value array (1) {[5417736] => string (1) "0"}
Now I want to check each order in which order the number of products is still zero, and if an order had a product with a value of zero, Ignore it and check the next order if it did not have a product with zero, the value in the order_lack column for each I can change the order

Comment: @user3783243 , yes , but how?

Comment: `in_array(0, array here)` would tell you if any of the values in the array had 0. Do what you ever you need to do in that event

Comment: thank you @user3783243 , now i have this : 
`bool(false) bool(false) bool(true) bool(false) bool(false)`

`5417736(false),5417736(false),5417736(true),1899299(false),1899299(false)`
i want if one array in `5417736` is false , break and then next order_code

Comment: `if(in_array(0, array here)) { break X;` break for the number of iterations in you want to stop on.